# Mustache.js / Hogan.js with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, mustache

I'm trying to implement some code using backbone.js
and hogan.js (http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/)

> Hogan.js was developed against the mustache test suite,
>   so everything that holds true for templates as
>   specified here, is also the case for hogan.js.

My problem is passing the Backbone.Collection to Hogan/Mustache.

For a simple template like this:

```
{{name}}
```

Hogan/Mustache expecting something like this works fine:

```
{"name":"How Bizarre","artist":"OMC"}
```

However my Backbone.Collection is:

a)
    [{"name":"How Bizarre","artist":"OMC"}]

Or this:

b)
    [{"name":"How Bizarre","artist":"OMC"}, {"name":"Sexual Healing","artist":"Marvin Gaye"}]

From the demo page http://mustache.github.com/#demo I cannot
iterate over either of the a) or b) Backbone.Collection obejcts.

Can anyone point out how I can do this?

```
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
name: "Not specified",
artist: "Not specified"
}
});

var Album = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Song
});

var song1 = new Song({ name: "How Bizarre", artist: "OMC" });
var song2 = new Song({ name: "Sexual Healing", artist: "Marvin Gaye" });

var myAlbum = new Album;

myAlbum.add(song1);
myAlbum.add(song2);
```

I am passing trying to render by passing my Backbone.Colleciton
object like this: myAlbum.toJSON()

```
var template = "{{name}}!";

var template = Hogan.compile(template);

this.el.html(template.render(myAlbum.toJSON()));
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think I got it OK.

    var stuff = {};

    stuff.items = myAlbum

This then allows me to:

    {{#items}}
    <b>{{name}}</b>
    {{/items}}

    {"items":[
    {"name":"How Bizarre","artist":"OMC"},
    {"name":"Sexual Healing","artist":"Marvin Gaye"}
    ]}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're passing a Collection to Hogan rather than an individual model.

Try this instead:

```
_.each(myAlbum,function(album) {
    this.el.append(template.render(album.toJSON()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same predicament, using Hogan templating on a Backbone collection.

```
var o = {},
c = Album.toJSON();
o.data = c;
this.$el.html(template.render(o));
```

and in my template i am referencing {{#data}} {{/data}} to iterate through the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I overrode the backbone render call

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = (template, data) ->
  HoganTemplates[template].render data
```

Works very well with marionette. having issues with backbone.forms though.